# How to call asynchronous method synchronously in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

We have existing iOS application developed using Xamarin.Forms. Now we want to extend to both Android and Windows Phone. In the existing application, all the web service calls are made synchronously. Windows phone supports only asynchronous calling, so we thought of wrapping the asynchronous calls to synchronous.

We are using HttpClient.PostAsync method to access the service. Once the execution hits PostAsync method, the phone hangs. The code to call the service is as follows:

```
private static async void CallService(System.Uri uri)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = uri.Host;
        client.Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

        var configuredClient = client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var resp = configuredClient.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        responseString = resp.StatusCode.ToString();
        resp.Dispose();

        client.CancelPendingRequests();
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I know this is because of blocking the UI thread, so only I implemented ConfigureAwait(false) but that didn't work at all. I tried with System.Net.WebClient also but the same result.

Now, how I will make this asynchronous call to process synchronously in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: I think all you need to do is drop the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` as that may lead to the next line executing on context - the thread pool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all avoid using *async void* methods,because you can't easily wait for its completion. Return `Task` instead, being inside `async` method you don't need to do something special to return a `Task`. Compiler does all the work for you.

You need to await the call to `HttpClient.PostAsync`, that should be enough to keep the UI responsive.

```
private static async Task CallService(System.Uri uri)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = uri.Host;
        client.Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

        var resp = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);// Await it
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        responseString = resp.StatusCode.ToString();
        resp.Dispose();

        client.CancelPendingRequests();
    }
}
```

Note: I've removed the `ConfigureAwait(false)` as that's not required. If you really need it, you may add it back.

Comment: if you're `using` the client, you don't need to dispose at the end either - the using block will dispose automatically at the end.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy You're right, updated, thanks. I just worked on the relevant part. Rest all OP's code.

Comment: Don't think that will build without `async Task` in the method header.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for mentioning. That's a typo.